# TestNG: How to link IConfigurationListener2.beforeConfiguration ITestResult to ITestListener.onTestStart

Tags: java, unit-testing, automated-tests, testng, java-threads

I have 2 TestNG listeners which report logging information to a log file for debugging information. These are `IConfigurationListener2` and `ITestListener`. The test run in multiple threads.

My issue is that I need to link the ITestResult in the `IConfigurationListener2.onConfigurationFailure()` method to the `ITestListener.onTestStart()` `ITestResult` to retrieve the `@Test` `ITestResult.getMethodName()`. Is this possible?

`TestListener` Code is:

```
public class TestListener implements ITestListener{
    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {       
        System.out.println("Starting test method:" + result.getMethod().getMethodName());
    }
}
```

`IConfigurationListener2` is:

```
public class ConfigurationListener implements IConfigurationListener2 {
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("Failed to run " + result.getMethod().getMethodName()
            + " for the test method:" + <code needed>);
}
```

The `TestNG` Class is:

```
public class Script1 {

private int i =0;
@BeforeMethod
public void before(){
    System.out.println("Starting before");
    i++;
    if (i==1){
        throw new RuntimeException("forcing an exception");
    }
}

@Test(testName="script1")
public void script1_run(){
    System.out.println("Running script");
}

@Test(testName="script2")
public void script2_run(){
    System.out.println("Running script");
}
}
```

So how do I find out which `@Test` method the `@beforeMethod` failed for. I would like the log something like this:

Starting before
Starting test method:script1_run
Running script
Starting before
**Failed to run before for the test method: script2_run**

Thanks,

Comment: What is logged instead currently?

Comment: I am testing a new application and building the framework up. At the moment noting is logged, I just see that tests are skipped which is caused by the Configuration method failing, hence why I need to add logging information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge your 2 listeners:

```
public class MyNewListener implements IConfigurationListener2, ITestListener {

  private final ThreadLocal<ITestResult> currentTest = new ThreadLocal<>();

  @Override
  public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println("Starting test method:" + result.getMethod().getMethodName());
    currentTest.set(result);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationFailure(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println("Failed to run " + result.getMethod().getMethodName()
            + " for the test method:" + currentTest.get().getMethod().getMethodName());
  }
}
```

The `ThreadLocal` is used to keep track across the parallel run.

Disclaimer: I didn't test the listener in real life. Tell me if it is working or not.

Edit: Tests are supposed to be skipped after a failed configuration method

```
public class MyNewListener implements IConfigurationListener2, ITestListener {

  private final ThreadLocal<ITestResult> failedConfiguration = new ThreadLocal<>();

  @Override
  public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println("Starting test method:" + result.getMethod().getMethodName());
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationFailure(ITestResult result) {
    failedConfiguration.set(result);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println("Failed to run " + failedConfiguration.get().getMethod().getMethodName()
            + " for the test method:" + result.getMethod().getMethodName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did now work. This is down to the `onConfigurationFailure()` being called before the `onTestStart()` method and returns null. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: @T.Daves Ok! I've just updated my answer with another proposition. Let me know its result! :)

Comment: I can confirm that edited answer worked. I did something similar yesterday and now working on `@AfterMethod` and log this in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! :) You should post your `@AfterMethod` too in case someone needs it a day ;)